# Primefaces p:dataTable changing default value message "No records found."?

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a p:dataTable:

```
<p:dataTable var="ind" value="#{logIndPersistBean.list}" paginator="true" rows="10"
                        id="table"  rowStyleClass="odd-row, even-row">

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            List of Logs
                        </f:facet>

                        <p:column headerText="Name" >
                            <h:outputText value="#{ind.name}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Date" >
                            <h:outputText value="#{ind.date}" />
                        </p:column>

                        </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>
```

When i start a new search, if none register returns, the dataTable show a message "No records found.", is there a way to a dataTable just show a empty message, only the empty list ?

I know is possible just Add emptyMessage="" to your data table attributes.

I want to change de default message in every p:dataTable, is it possible, instead "No records found." change this message to "Your query returned no record." or just changing the default value for "".

If it's relevant i'm using primefaces 4.0

[image]

Thanks in advance.

I foud a solution:

Three ways: 
1. Change Primefaces.

2. Develop a composite component which wrap the P:datatable and change the emptymessage to what you what.
3. Use  (replace p:datatable) and  (wrapping). It's essentially same as 2, but easier.

But, what really work well for me was to change the css, my doubt has a different answer of a topic marked as duplicated :

```
 .ui-widget-content .ui-datatable-empty-message{ display: none;}
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Since you posted the answer in the question itself instead of as a normal answer to the duplicate question, I've edited my answer over there.

Comment: No problem, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possibe since that message is not defined in `Messages.properties` file, so you can't override it.